# Writing a query for pop up box in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp, popup

I want my mysql query to be executed when the user clicks on delete button on the pop up box.I have button named 'Delete' and when  the user clicks on the button a confirm box pops up and if the user clicks ok then the data should be deleted.I am not asking the query i want to know where should i write the code and how.I have written the code for button in controller and i have called a function in view.Please help as i have just started on cake and don't know i suppose anything about it.

Comment: book.cakephp.org - reading documentation is the first step and usually a common part of a programmers job. Read about MVC and conventions then do the blog tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set it in the onclick options of your button.
eg:

```
$this->Form->input('Submit',array(
    'type' => 'button',
    'onclick' => 'alert"Are you sure'));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes now i have figured it out.I sent the data on 'onclick' to the view and then from view i sent the data again to the controller and then on the controller i wrote the custom query for deletion.Its working perfectly.